# Custom scrollbar on v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, scroll, vuetify.js, scrollbar, v-data-table

I try to change style on v-data-table (vuetify). This code changes scrolls on all places (browser scrolls too).

```css
<style>
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 24px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #143861;
}
</style>
```

How can I change scroll style for a specific element? These solutions don't work:

```css
<style>
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 24px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #143861;
}
</style>
```

```html
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
          item-key="id"
          id="element"
        >
        </v-data-table>
```

```css
<style>
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 24px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #143861;
}
</style>
```

```html
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
          item-key="id"
          class="element"
        >
        </v-data-table>
```

Comment: Try using `<style scoped>`

Comment: I tried it. In this case style is not changed even for browser

Comment: Hi, Have a look at this codepen, is it what you are looking for? https://codepen.io/eddie1952/pen/jObPvKO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target `v-data-table` inner element which is scrollable:

```css
.element .v-data-table__wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 24px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #143861;
}
```